# SELECT from a table twice in the same query

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join, alias

I have a table per below, which riches with:

```
SELECT 
    origin_airport_id, destination_airport_id, hour, minute 
FROM 
    flights 
WHERE 
    year = 2021 AND month = 7 AND day = 28;
```

[image]

Then two columns are generated with two below queries respectively (left to right):

```
SELECT city 
FROM airports 
JOIN flights ON airports.id = flights.origin_airport_id 
WHERE flights.year = 2021 AND flights.month = 7 AND flights.day = 28;
```

and

```
SELECT city 
FROM airports 
JOIN flights ON airports.id = flights.destination_airport_id 
WHERE flights.year = 2021 AND flights.month = 7 AND flights.day = 28;
```

[image]

[image]

These are the two related table schemas:

[image]

How can the two columns (`origin_airport_id` and `destination_airport_id` in `flights` table) be SELECTed from `city` column of the `airport` table?

In fact how can we select `city` column twice in the same query?

This means I want to replace the two first column of the first picture here with `city`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the create table statement and the data as text into your request instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must join `flights` to 2 copies of `airports`:

```
SELECT orig.city AS orig_city,
       dest.city AS dest_city,
       f.hour,
       f.minute
FROM flights AS f
JOIN airports AS orig ON orig.id = f.origin_airport_id 
JOIN airports AS dest ON dest.id = f.origin_destination_id 
WHERE f.year = 2021 AND f.month = 7 AND f.day = 28;
```